# NSIS Use selected language for uninstaller

Tags: dialog, nsis, uninstallation

I am working on NSIS installer and I just added multi language to the installer.
I wanted the Installer to show the language dialog everytime the user click on the installer, so I removed those two lines from my nsi file

```
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY}"
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
```

this one also force the uninstaller to show the language dialog everytime the user click on it.

I would like to disable the language dialog in the installer OR to make it use the language the user selected when installed the program << this way is better.

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the $language variable in the registry during install and read it into $language in un.onInit. If you don't want to display the language dialog, don't call it in .onInit

Comment: How do I save it in the registry and then during the install read it?

Comment: @Ron: In a section, use WriteRegDWORD to save $language (You could probably save it in the same place as the uninstall information) and in the uninstaller, use ReadRegDWORD $language HKLM "software\...path here\" language in un.onInit

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Function un.onInit

  !insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
  
FunctionEnd
```

You need to have MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_* setup as well like this:

```
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "HKCU" 
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\YourAppName" 
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Installer Language"
```